# In C#, How can I sort a collection by a property in an object?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a collection of Person objects and a person can belong to many teams

```
public class Person
{
     public List<string> Teams();
}
```

so I have a collection of these objects

```
List<Person> people = GetPeople();
```

Now given the collection I want to get the list of most used teams

I can get a full list of all teams by doing this:

```
   var teams = people.SelectMany(r=>r.Teams);
```

or I can get a distinct list of teams by doing this:

```
   var teams = people.SelectMany(r=>r.Teams).Distinct(new TeamComparer());
```

but I now want to get the top 10 teams.

What is the correct way to sort teams by the most used?  So for example if I have

```
  var person = new Person(){Teams = new List<string>{"Team A", "Team D"} }
  var person2 = new Person(){Teams = new List<string>{"Team B", "Team C"} }
  var person3 = new Person(){Teams = new List<string>{"Team B", "Team C"} }
  var person4 = new Person(){Teams = new List<string>{"Team B", "Team D"} }
```

so in the example above, it would return in order:

Team B
Team C
Team D
Team A

Comment: what do you mean by most used?

Comment: The [OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) extension method should do what your question title asks...

Comment: Based on your edit, i would go with @dasblinkenlight's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get ten teams with the highest usage count, you should group them, rather than eliminating the duplicates using `Distinct()`. Once you have your groups, sort by group count, and take the first ten, like this:

```
var topTen = people
    .SelectMany(r => r.Teams)          // Get the teams with duplicates
    .GroupBy(t => t)                   // Group by team
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count()) // Sort by count
    .Take(10)                          // Take top ten
    .Select(g => g.Key)                // Drop groups
    .ToList();                         // Make a list
```

Comment: The only thing I'd do is change the select to : `.Select(g => new {team=g.Key, count=g.Count()})` so he can see the count as well , but great otherwise

Answer (score -1):

```
List<Person> lstpeople = GetPeople();
lstPerson = lstPerson.OrderBy(x => x.personID).toList();
lstPerson = lstPerson.orderbydescending(x => x.personID).toList();
```

Comment: `toList` is invalid C#. It should be `ToList()`.